# Why doesn't Apache display 404 errors with Django and mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, django, apache2

With my current Apache & Django setup, when I go to a page that does not exist, the root page for the website is displayed rather than a 404 error. Here is my httpd.conf file:

```
Alias /robots.txt /var/www/sov/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/sov/static/favicon.ico

Alias /static /var/www/sov/static/

<Directory /var/www/sov/static>
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
#Order deny,allow
#AllowOverride all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/sov/scripts/django.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/sov/scripts/mcsite>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Why is this happening? If possible, I would like to keep the WSGIScriptAlias as it is at the root. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG=False` in your settings file?

Comment: @FrancisYaconiello Nope, DEBUG=True. Even if it was false, shouldn't Apache give its 404 page?

Comment: not necessarily, django catches the 404 and tries to route it internally to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view

Comment: @FrancisYaconiello Ah. Well, when I tried to define a custom 404 page with Django the same thing still occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `mod_wsgi` Django is responsible for showing 404 pages (not Apache).

This fails because you have bug in your main urls.py file. You probably have following code:

```
url('', my_home_view),
```

but you should have:

```
url('^$' my_home_view),
```

Show your urls file if my guess isn't correct.